# Jssor slider is not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slider, jssor

I have a Jssor slider which is running fine with the jQuery version. But when I put the code and JS files into my AngularJS app, it is not working. I get the following error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of undefined

Is there any specific way to work with Jssor slider in AngularJS?

```js
var app = angular.module('slider', []);

app.controller('sliderCtrl', function($scope){
  this.slides = [
    {heading: 'movies', number: 115, panel: 'panel-green'},
    {heading: 'viewed', number: 252 , panel: 'panel-primary'},
    {heading: 'streams', number: 354 , panel: 'panel-yellow'},
    {heading: 'length', number: 471 , panel: 'panel-green'},
    {heading: 'Spent', number: 589, panel: 'panel-red'},
    {heading: 'viewed two', number: 789 ,panel: 'panel-yellow'},
    {heading: 'streams two', number: 412 , panel: 'panel-green'},
    {heading: 'length two', number: 456, panel: 'panel-red'}    
  ];
  $scope.data = this;
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row" id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
        <div id="slider1_container">
            <div u="slides" class="slides" class="col-lg-2 col-custom-lg-2 col-md-4">
                <div ng-repeat="div in data.slides" class="panel {{div.panel}}">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <div class="huge">{{div.number}}</div>
                                <div >{{div.heading}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l arrowleft"></span>            
            <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r arrowright"></span>        
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just tried the above code and it is working in my main HTML layout. However, when I put it into my template, it is not working and I encounter the same error.

Comment: could you please share the code?

Comment: Did you forget to include  jssor.core.js and jssor.utils.js ?

Comment: No, I included both js

Comment: As far as I remembered, sometimes, its becuase of initlization syntax in jssor, check out some like, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812214/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326238/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Or there is problem 
with jssor initialization. It's better to create directive for jssor slider. [Here](https://github.com/adebisi-fa/dang-jssor) is already AngularJS directive for jssor slider. Use it!

Comment: I tried with ng-class but not working with it..
and adebisi-fa/dang-jssor slider does not contain the full slider pack.